# New symbol in math mode; add "equal" line below glyph

Tags: symbols, math-operators

I was trying to find a workaround providing a single line below a glyph in maths mode. That is, I would like to achieve something similar to the maths symbols `\leq` and `\subseteq` as opposed to `<` and `\subset`, respectively, but with another glyph.

I have tried several workarounds using the `accents` package (that is, `\underaccent`) and a combination of `\underset` and `\raisebox`. My attempts follow:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\subseteq$ $\subset$ \raisebox{0.1em}{$\underaccent{\bar}{\in}$} \raisebox{0.1em}{$\underset{\bar{}}{\in}$} \raisebox{0.1em}{\underline{$\in$}}

\end{document}
```

In particular, I am looking for the `\in` symbol with such a single line below.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks, Rance

EDIT: I apologise, I wasn't specific enough in my original post; I would like a symbol that looks *good* in the sense that it is in line with its analogues `\subseteq` and `\leq`. That is, the single equal line below has rounded edges, and its length matches the width of the `\in`-glyph precisely. That is what I'd like to achieve.
That exactly is why I refrained from using the attempted symbols I provided in my original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weren't for the sharp cuts this seems to do what you need.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\ineq{}% for safety
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ineq}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\rance@ineq\relax}}
\newcommand{\rance@ineq}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    $\m@th#1\mkern1.5mu\underline{\mkern-1.5mu\in\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern1.5mu$%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\subseteq$ $\subset$ $\ineq$ $\in$

$\ineq_{\ineq}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`accents` seems to be using definitions in amsmath, you could simply move it to after `\usepackage{amsmath}` and then your code would work and would generate the required symbols.

However, there is no need for `accents` for the last symbol which seems to be what you're looking for. `\underline{\in}` is sufficient.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

you could simply use it like so $\underline{\in}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, that doesn't look very good compared to `\subseteq` and `\leq`. I have edited my original post.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two variants with `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\ineq{\stackMath\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{0.03em}{c}{-1.5ex}{\mathord{\relbar}}{\in}}}
\newcommand\varineq{\stackMath\mathrel{\stackinset{c}{0.03em}{c}{-1.57ex}{\mathord{\relbar}}{\raisebox{0.2ex}{$ \in $}}}}


\begin{document}

 $A\ineq B\subseteq C$

 $A\varineq B\subseteq C$

\end{document}
```

[image]